# Hide input text after entering, hide password after entering

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, css

Well the situation is like this: i have form to login on my page with 2 textboxes, so one is for username and other for password, I am using razor and asp.net mvc 3 so my pasword textbox is already displaying little circles instead of password chars.
Can i somehow make it to work like this: I am entering my passwork but i see what char it is but after 2 or 3 seconds my char become a circle/dot which is default for entering paswords.

I hope someone has solution or advice for achieveing this?

Comment: do you mean like what mobile devices do?

Comment: Yes like entering pin in mobile devices :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this jquery plugin [iphone like jquery plugin](http://blog.decaf.de/2009/07/iphone-like-password-fields-using-jquery/)

Answer (score 1):

Can you explain to my why you would do that!? I think it's better to let the browser deal with providing a UI that is consistent! Also, those kinds of solutions rarely (if ever) deliver across all platforms. The example that I post here is really cludgy on the iPhone, for example.

Comment: Well google is my friend but iphone is not, i forgot to search it this way on google :)